# Changing a single index of a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change just **a particular** index of a Series. The indices are `Date`s. `cashflow_series` is the Series, and I am just trying to add a certain number of months to this date by using `replace(month = cashflow_series.index[k].month + dict_no_months_between_payments[count])` on the index and use this to replace the previous index date. I am currently using `reindex` but that would change all the indices and hence I'm stuck as to how to change just one index.

```
index_here = cashflow_series.index[k]
cashflow_series.index[k] = cashflow_series.index[k].reindex(index=index_here.replace(month = cashflow_series.index[k].month + dict_no_months_between_payments[count]))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pandas, an index is frozen (it is immutable and will give the following error if you try to change a value in the index):

> TypeError: '' does not support
>   mutable operations.

You need to create a copy of the old index values, modify it, and then replace the one in your series with this copy.  Something like:

```
idx = df.index.values
idx[3] = '2015-8-15'
df.index = idx
```

Comment: Is that the only way to modify a single index value?

Comment: There is usually more than one way to skin a cat, but the index values are immutable so you cannot just arbitrarily change them. You would need to create a new index with the desired values.