# Editing Indices of Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to edit the indices of the series `bond.to_cash_flows().amounts`. I actually asked a similar question to this before and was able to use the answer. However, using the [answer to the question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31995240/changing-a-single-index-of-a-series/31995537#31995537) for a slightly different purpose is not giving me the right result, in that the last print statement in this code shows that `bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index` is the same as before. I don't know how else to attempt to change the Indices of a Series.

```
 idx = bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index.values
 #I then make a few edits to idx and the print statement below reflects that it works
 print(idx) #Comes out as expected
 bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index = idx
 print('ind', bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index) #Remains same as before
```

Thank You

Comment: bond.to_cash_flows() will return a dataframe based on your proprietary code.  Without seeing the code of this function, it is unlikely anyone can further help you.  bond.to_cash_flows?? should print the code for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `bond.to_cash_flows()` returns a new `DataFrame` every time its called.

Then the line:

```
 bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index=idx
```

Has no effect, since calling

```
print('ind', bond.to_cash_flows().amounts.index)
```

Will create a fresh `DataFrame` with the original index.